# Dynamically add an empty row with jdbc?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to add an empty record to a MySQL database from Java regardless of how many columns the table has or what data type the columns are.

So far I've come up with this approach:

```
//Add first value 0 cause its probably the primary key ID with auto incrementation
    String emptyColumns="\"0\",";
//Loop through the remaining columns ( without the first one and the last one)
//and add for each column an empty value with a comma, eg "", 
    for(int i=2; i<nrCols; i++){
    emptyColumns=emptyColumns+"\"\",";
    }
//For the last column add an empty value without comma, eg ""
   emptyColumns=emptyColumns+"\"\"";    
    addNewRecord = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("Insert into " +selectedTable + " VALUES(" + emptyColumns + ");");
    addNewRecord.executeUpdate();
```

The problem is this doesn't work if the table has a date column or if the first column is not a primary key auto-incrementing id column.

How can I add an empty record regardless of the table's structure?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score -1):

For primery key you do not supply a value, the database will insert it for you. If the column is date you need to pass null (if not null) or the correct syntax, ex: **STR_TO_DATE('1-01-2012', '%d-%m-%Y')**